# CometD - How to run demo in tomcat jetty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cometd

Im trying run the demo aps in CometD. I have installed Maven. I have followed the commands [here](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#d0e117). In my console it displays `[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 1 seconds.`
. I went to `http://localhost:8080/` and see apache tomcat main page but I can't see any project. How can I see those projects. I want to test the demos. Please help.

Btw, below is the displayed log in the console after I run the command `mvn jetty:deploy-war` to start the jetty server:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CometD :: Demo 2.5.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.7.v20120910:deploy-war (default-cli) @ cometd-demo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1.1:enforce (enforce-maven-version) @ cometd-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.7.v20120910:deploy-war (default-cli) @ cometd-demo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:7.6.7.v20120910:deploy-war (default-cli) @ cometd-demo ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: CometD :: Demo
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /home/tom/cometd-2.5.0/cometd-demo/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
2012-11-08 11:30:14.862:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.7.v20120910
2012-11-08 11:30:15.311:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2012-11-08 11:30:15.742:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/home/tom/cometd-2.5.0/cometd-demo/target/tmp/webapp/},/home/tom/cometd-2.5.0/cometd-demo/target/cometd-demo-2.5.0.war
2012-11-08 11:30:16,026 main [ INFO][AnnotationCometdServlet] Processed annotated service org.cometd.examples.ChatService@1d91eb90
2012-11-08 11:30:16,027 main [ INFO][AnnotationCometdServlet] Registered annotated service org.cometd.examples.ChatService@1d91eb90 in servlet context
2012-11-08 11:30:16,105 main [ INFO][CometdDemoServlet] Monitored Subscribe from seti_51cw11a1uy7x5ygbmosqpdkirv - last connect 0 ms ago for /seti/http_localhost_8080_cometd
2012-11-08 11:30:16,109 main [ INFO][CometdDemoServlet] Monitored Subscribe from seti_51cw11a1uy7x5ygbmosqpdkirv - last connect 0 ms ago for /seti/all
2012-11-08 11:30:16,118 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#bids to /auction/*
2012-11-08 11:30:16,119 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#bid to /service/auction/bid
2012-11-08 11:30:16,119 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#bidder to /service/auction/bidder
2012-11-08 11:30:16,119 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#search to /service/auction/search
2012-11-08 11:30:16,119 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#category to /service/auction/category
2012-11-08 11:30:16,119 main [DEBUG][AuctionService] Mapping oortion#categories to /service/auction/categories
2012-11-08 11:30:16,122 main [DEBUG][AuctionChatService] Mapping chat#trackMembers to /auction/chat/**
2012-11-08 11:30:16,122 main [DEBUG][AuctionChatService] Mapping chat#privateChat to /service/auction/chat
2012-11-08 11:30:16.137:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 1 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

The logs show that [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) started correctly, and I just tried the same instructions, obtaining the same logs and I can see the [CometD](http://cometd.org) home page when I point the browser to localhost:8080.

If you see a different page, then probably your browser has cached it; try to hard reload the page.

You have done everything right, I think it's just the browser caching aggressively.

Note that the commands you issued will start Jetty, not Tomcat.

However, you can deploy manually the CometD war into Tomcat to have CometD work in Tomcat, although running CometD in Jetty is recommended.

Comment: Thanks. I actually fixed this one by repeating the same process. I don't know the real reason why it didn't work the first time I tried it. Maybe I just missed something.